# Git merge -X theirs not merging all changes

Tags: git, git-merge

I've checked out a branch and I want to merge in master. The branch is behind master, since master hasn't been merged with this branch in two weeks, so I want to use all changes from master.

I do the following:

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs master
```

For the most part it merges, but there are at least a couple spots where conflicts didn't from theirs.

For instance, there is one line:

```
#import "VMVideo_Private.h"
```

This was taken out from master at some point in the last two weeks but since this branch hasn't been merged in the last two weeks it's still there in the branch.

After the merge using `theirs`, it's still there.

Furthermore, if I try to merge manually with just a:

```
git merge master
```

This particular conflict does not come up at all.

Answer (score 4):

In the recursive merge strategy, `-X theirs` (or for that matter `-X ours`) simply means that *in the case of conflicts* it should automatically resolve the conflict by choosing "their version" (or "our version", with `-X ours`).

If there is *no* conflict, your `-X` selection does not come into play at all.

For instance, suppose that in the original (common merge-base) version, file `foo.txt`, line 34, said `Rumplestiltskin`.  Suppose further that you changed this to `George Clooney`.  And, finally, suppose that file `foo.txt` was in fact changed in `master`, but nowhere near line 34.  Now you ask git to merge their (master's) changes with yours: it keeps your change, where Rumplestiltskin becomes Clooney, as there is no conflict with their changes, where `foo.txt` now claims to be true instead of false.  The resulting merge now makes claims (which it claims are true) about Mr Clooney, rather than about a fairy-tale character.

(In some cases, git—which is just doing a `diff` of the various versions—will decide that the changes you and they made to some code (or text) is best represented by something that, semantically, is quite meaningless.  For C and Java code, for instance, it may falsely synchronize on lines with nothing but a close-brace.  The resulting merges can be hilariously, or tragically, bad.  Sometimes choosing a modified diff algorithm, e.g., "patience diff", can help.  Sometimes nothing helps.)

Answer (score 3):

Most of time it is your branches are merged back and force and the root of each diverge points hide the difference. There is a trick to fix it.

Suppose you want to merge from *master* to your current branch *cur*, after doing

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs master
git commit
```

then do (you have to commit first):

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol cur..master | git apply
```

This simply compares the merged *cur* and *master* branches, and the diff will be picked up and applied as a patch.

Comment: This appears to be designed to re-adjust `cur` to exactly match `master`.  That's not a merge, that's a clobber (a la `git merge -s ours`, which is also a clobber, but in the other direction).  If you want a clobber merge in the "theirs" direction, that's easy to do in one commit, although it takes multiple git commands.

Comment: No. This is to re-adjust *cur* to **contain** everything in *master*.

Comment: How would you distinguish "contain everything" from "exactly match" (aside from end of line white-space)?  For instance, suppose `cur` has file `new.txt` that does not exist in `master`.  The `git diff ... | git apply` will *remove* new.txt.  Obviously I must then stage and commit the result of apply, but once I do, `cur` now matches `master`.